# Access django main page by its name not ip

Tags: python, django, web

is there a way to configure a Django server in that way so I can open my local webpage by typing 'weatherstation.local' and not by the IP:port?

Comment: It is a question about networking, not about django. You can do it only in your local network while having the `weatherstation` machine's hostname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your router you might be able to set DNS. if DNS administration exists, then here you can set different domain names for IP addresses on your network.

You can give your ip address multiple domain names, and then you can use somthing like NGINX to route the domain calls to different services that you are running on your server.

Good luck, I hope this was helpful ;-)